# How to check latest version of iOS in Swift without using @available?

Tags: ios, swift

How can we check if the OS running on iPhone is the latest one. Is there any API for that?
For example, user is using iOS 14.6, so I want to know if its the latest version that he is using

I know this code is for checking, what OS user is having. This is not the answer at all. Please read the question before closing

```
if (@available(iOS 14.6, *)) {
    // Use iOS 11 APIs.
} else {
    // Alternative code for earlier versions of iOS.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No there is no way except `available` only if you created a personal Api to provide this info for your app automatically when opened